# Merge 2 data frames using values of column vector from dataframe with and column of list from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Say I have two data frames,

```
df1.head()
AH1
A
B
C
D
F
```

The second data frame `df2.head()`

```
AH1 BC
A,B SAP
C,D XY
A,B,C   BMZ
A,F Zoom
```

What I need is to merge the columns `AH1` from two data frames `df1` and `df2`based on the same values. In the end, I am aiming to have something like this,

```
output
    AH1 BC
    A   SAP, BMZ,Zoom
    B   SAP,BMZ
    C   XY,BMZ
    D   XY
    F   Zoom
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. I know `pandas.merge` would go however not between column vector and column of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an `explode`:

```
(df2.assign(AH1=df2.AH1.str.split(','))
    .explode('AH1')
    .groupby('AH1')
    ['BC'].agg(list)
)
```

Output:

```
AH1
A    [SAP, BMZ, Zoom]
B          [SAP, BMZ]
C           [XY, BMZ]
D                [XY]
F              [Zoom]
Name: BC, dtype: object
```

Or replacing `agg(list)` with `agg(', '.join)`:

```
(df2.assign(AH1=df2.AH1.str.split(','))
    .explode('AH1')
    .groupby('AH1')
    ['BC'].agg(', '.join)
)
```

Output:

```
AH1
A    SAP, BMZ, Zoom
B          SAP, BMZ
C           XY, BMZ
D                XY
F              Zoom
Name: BC, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I will try.
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'`

Comment: Updated the python version and it helped! Thanks